Weird dots on page when attempting to create an attachment via fax SOAP API
For some context, I am using Make.com to send a SOAP API request that will send a fax programatically. I am trying to include an attachment within the XML request body using binary data and base64 encoding. I believe I correctly encoded the binary data into base64 with this code:
let bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(input);

let base64String = btoa(bytes);

return base64String

I then included "base64String" into the XML for the SOAP request which is here (Note that the XML isn't indented but it should still be correct):
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
<sendFax xmlns="http://ws.xm.faxserver.com/">
<userId xmlns="">testuser@test.com</userId>
<subject xmlns="">Test fax from Make</subject>
<comment xmlns="">This is a test fax sent from Make</comment>
<!-- Optional -->
<recipient xmlns="">
<number>1234567890</number>
<name>Test recipient</name>
<company>Test company</company>
</recipient>
<!-- Optional -->
<attachment xmlns="">
<name>[string]</name>
<contents>[base64Binary] THIS IS WHERE I INCLUDE THE ENCODED DATA</contents>
</attachment>
<!-- Optional -->
<senderInfo xmlns="">
<salutation>To whom it may concern</salutation>
<firstName>Justin</firstName>
<lastName>Domingo</lastName>
<title>ECM Technician</title>
<email>jdomingo@ubeo.com</email>
<company>UBEO</company>
</senderInfo>
<isCommentTypeHtml xmlns="">true</isCommentTypeHtml>
</sendFax>
</Body>
</Envelope>

As a result, everything executes properly with a status code of 200 but when I look at the fax, the attachment only shows this:
These are the weird dots
I tried encoding the binary data in different ways, I've tried including the binary data itself within the XML request, etc. Is there a certain step that I am missing?

Status code 200 indicates the connection completed and the server did not find anything wrong with the message.  That probably means the encoded fax data contains the weird dots or the fax format is not compatible with the fax machine you are using.
